# How to Ignore Case in group by for multiple columns in Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

please Find below the sample Query written for fetching data, I am looking for grouping the "GroupName" by ignoring the case of the word.

I am aware of below options and don't want to use these options which gives specific output format. Looking for retaining the original case.

1.TO Lower()
2.TO Lower()  will be in lower or upper case.

```
var GroupName = (from p in FilterList
                 where p.GroupName != null
                 group p by new { month = p.ReportedDateTime.Month, year = p.ReportedDateTime.Year, GroupName =p.GroupName  } into d
                 select new
                 {
                     dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}", d.Key.month, d.Key.year),
                         month = d.Key.month,
                         monthName = new DateTime(d.Key.year, d.Key.month, 1).ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                         count = d.Count(),
                         GroupName = d.Key.GroupName 
                 }).OrderByDescending(g => g.count)
                   .ThenBy(g => g.GroupName).Take(20);
```

How can I use "StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase" in the above query for the GroupName column.

Comment: The = operator on strings is always case sensitive (AFAIK). Have you tried using the `String.Equals` function which does have an overload for a comparer object?

Comment: Nostromo, i am actually looking for grouping the string , so equals will not workout,

Comment: how about `ThenBy(g => g.GroupName.ToLower())`

Comment: pm100, i dont want to use ToLower() , as my complete output will be in lower case, i want to retain the input data case as well.

Comment: Grouping by `ToLower` will reduce the `Key` to lowercase, but for each `IGrouping`, `First().GroupName` will still have the original case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ToLower` on the grouping key and retrieve the original case from one of the group members. This won't be the same as the original case of all of the group members, but that is implied by wanting to group ignoring case and not keeping all the group members in the answer.

```
var GroupName = (from p in FilterList
                 where p.GroupName != null
                 group p by new { month = p.ReportedDateTime.Month, year = p.ReportedDateTime.Year, GroupName = p.GroupName.ToLower()  } into d
                 select new {
                     dt = string.Format("{0}/{1}", d.Key.month, d.Key.year),
                         month = d.Key.month,
                         monthName = new DateTime(d.Key.year, d.Key.month, 1).ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                         count = d.Count(),
                         GroupName = d.First().GroupName
                 }).OrderByDescending(g => g.count)
                   .ThenBy(g => g.GroupName).Take(20);
```

Comment: great, this is working for some times and not working in some scenarios.

Comment: Explain those scenarios or perhaps ask another question?

Comment: Netmage - i was doing something wrong for one scenario, this is working now all the scenarios. thanks.